# What do you call the square brackets in a camera app or QR scanner?

Tags: terminology

What do you call the square brackets used to target a barcode/QR scanner? I thought this would be called "reticle," but when I Google the term, all I see are circles with crosshairs. Is there a more precise term, especially in the context of a digital device/camera, or is reticle the word?

[image: scanner target]

Comment: Seems more like a question for http://english.stackexchange.com When I search Google for "rectangle crosshairs" I get "**Crosshair box**".

Comment: I'd refer to it as a Viewfinder, though technically that could refer to the whole visible "view" you get on the phone.

Comment: So, how do I migrate it to english.stackexchange.com?

Comment: I don't know, you could repost there and close this.

Comment: No, don't cross-post to another SE site. If the mods on another site agree its more suitable on their sites then the mods on this site will migrate the question. However I think it's fine on UX as its an interface terminology question.

Comment: @BenBrocka your edit gives me a clue of where to start looking. It's something to do with the viewfinder.

Comment: I think the reason you find so many "crosshairs" for reticles is that the English-speaking (American) world has a very involved gun culture/history. A "crosshair" is a reticle, but not all reticles are crosshairs.

Comment: Etymologically speaking, reticle does come from crossing hairs: "reticulum" = net.

Comment: The answer probably depends on your audience:  one answer may be technically correct - but not actually mean anything to your audience.

Comment: Are your going to be using this term anywhere in the UI, or are you simply curious what this thing is called? I ask because it seems like you'd want to avoid terms like "reticle" if you want users to understand.

Comment: @tim That's a great question and I'm glad you asked. I plan mostly to use this internally, in which case I might use reticle. If I ever needed to express this concept to users, I would say "focus frame."

Comment: If you plan on using it internally, go with something correct e.g. "region of interest". If you want users to understand then "viewfinder box" or "crosshair box" are more common (judging by Google images' results) and easy for users to understand.

Comment: @DannyVarod I'm not in agreement with your terminology. "Region of interest" is unwieldy and actually vague: it doesn't denote any boundary to the region of interest. I don't see that crosshair box is common on Google outside of AutoCAD and gaming. "Focus frame" comes up more with cameras: e.g.  http://forums.dpreview.com/forums/readflat.asp?forum=1020&message=41383138&changemode=1

Comment: And for image results, the first gives me many more relevant results than the second: (1) https://www.google.com/search?q=%22focus+frame%22&hl=en&prmd=imvns&source=lnms&tbm=isch&ei=cmPXT7WuIeis8AGkioGOBQ&sa=X&oi=mode_link&ct=mode&cd=2&ved=0CEYQ_AUoATgU&biw=1428&bih=933 (2) https://www.google.com/search?q=%22crosshair+box%22&hl=en&prmd=imvnsfd&source=lnms&tbm=isch&ei=U2PXT_TIDsi58AHc5YyOBQ&sa=X&oi=mode_link&ct=mode&cd=2&ved=0CEEQ_AUoATge&biw=1428&bih=933

Comment: @tajmo try searching for: "focus frame" qr, "viewfinder box" qr, "viewfinder rectangle" qr and "viewfinder area" qr in Google images (with the quotes). The last 3 searches will result in relevant images (including first or second result). "focus frame" qr will not have any relevant results in the first row. Focus frame is specific to where the camera should focus on. The viewfinder box/rectangle/area is used by QR readers as a "region of interest" and the QR readers scan the image region inside the box only.

Comment: @dannyvarod I'm not having the same experience as you with Google: nothing particularly relevant in first row for any of them. I believe the term QR is what's garnering the relevant results, not the quoted terms. Region of interest looks like it has technical currency, but is still vague in terms of this particular application (camera and scanner apps). It just doesn't roll off the tongue, and the initialism is the same as "return on investment," so that won't work.

Comment: See the new query links at the of my answer. The quotes around "viewfinder box" make Google search for entire term, not unattached words and QR limits the results so that they will only include viewfinder boxes used for QRs.

Comment: Also see the first relevant result from each term behind the links I placed on each term.

Comment: @DannyVarod I'm still not convinced, but one of your references did point to "target area," which (palm to forehead) is brilliantly simple. I'm calling it good.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Colloquial: *Target Area,* *Focus Area,* or *Focus Frame***
It looks like "[target area](http://www.google.com/imgres?hl=en&biw=1428&bih=933&tbm=isch&tbnid=3bqqeUAwteODEM%3a&imgrefurl=http://www.androidapps-home.com/quickmark-barcode-scanner-android-6963.html&docid=Nbr4x3pvKwmdGM&imgurl=http://ssl.gstatic.com/android/market/tw.com.quickmark/ss-320-1-7&w=320&h=480&ei=7G7XT6L5DOms8AGi_vyNBQ&zoom=1&iact=hc&vpx=181&vpy=175&dur=953&hovh=275&hovw=183&tx=100&ty=130&sig=106342795571774308654&page=1&tbnh=154&tbnw=104&start=0&ndsp=38&ved=1t:429,r:0,s:0,i:75)" is the most straightforward term. "Focus frame" is the best colloquial phrase from photography, given that it is often referred to as an "AF (autofocus) Frame" or "focus frame" in camera manuals and discussions. There is some reference to "focus area," which is also descriptive and easy to understand:

1. http://qrganize.com/features.php
2. http://www.butkus.org/chinon/chinon/cp-9af/cp-9af.htm
3. http://forums.dpreview.com/forums/readflat.asp?forum=1020&message=41383138&changemode=1
4. http://www.sds.com/mug/9xi_vfdr.html
5. http://www.scoop.it/t/fuji-x-pro1/p/1758069851/do-you-read-the-manual-tip-3-focus-frame-to-center-fujifilm-digital-camera-x-pro1-owner-s-manual
6. http://www.scoop.it/t/fuji-x-pro1/p/1884969260/do-you-read-the-manual-tip-7-corrected-af-frame-fujifilm-digital-camera-x-pro1-owner-s-manual
7. http://www.sds.com/mug/700si-inf3.html
8. http://www.sds.com/mug/9xi_vfdr.html

**Technical: *Reticle* or *Crosshairs***
[Reticle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reticle) (or "crosshairs") is a term originating with telescopes, microscopes, and oscilloscopes, to name a few. Because scopes are round, "reticle" generally implies a circular view with cross hairs. However, the term is technically accurate when describing focus areas in cameras (credit goes to @mawcsco for finding the reference): http://www.reticles.com/reticles_kr900.htm. Here's another interesting reference: http://www.techniquip.com/manuals/DCG-200MManual_r3.pdf.

**Alternative Colloquial: *Crosshair Box***
Although I believe the above terms to be more generally understandable in reference to cameras, scanners and similar apps, the term "crosshair box" does show up colloquially as a [reference to the "pick box"](http://usa.autodesk.com/adsk/servlet/u/gsearch/results?siteID=123112&catID=123155&id=2088334&qt=crosshair%20box&x=0&y=0) in AutoDesk's product AutoCAD, for virtual cameras in gaming environments, and in one found reference to the reticle on a telescope:

1. http://usa.autodesk.com/adsk/servlet/u/gsearch/results?siteID=123112&catID=123155&id=2088334&qt=crosshair+box&x=0&y=0
2. http://www.garagegames.com/community/forums/viewthread/48233
3. http://www.astropix.com/HTML/I_ASTROP/TRACKED/MANUAL.HTM
4. http://community.bistudio.com/wiki/Camera.sqs

**iOS Term: *Focus Indicator***
Apple uses a similar element called the "[focus indicator](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AudioVideo/Conceptual/CameraAndPhotoLib_TopicsForIOS/Articles/TakingPicturesAndMovies.html)" in the camera app, however this square moves to indicate where the focus is, rather than form a fixed frame in the viewfinder.

**Other Camera Terms**
Cameras use "viewfinders," for the entire viewable area, "[bright line frame](http://www.butkus.org/chinon/chinon/intrafocus_35f-ma/body09.jpg)" and "[frame finder](http://www.mir.com.my/rb/photography/companies/nikon/nikkoresources/RF-Nikkor/RF-Accessories/Nikon-RF-Finders/KelSportFrame_3.jpg)" for the area inside the viewfinder.

Comment: The references in this answer include Asian language translations. I don't think Asian translators are the authority on the correct word. The people that actually make the glass etching that goes into cameras call them reticles.  http://www.reticles.com/reticles_kr900.htm

Comment: Refactored answer to include numerous references and differentiation between colloquial and technical terms. Bounty awarded to @mawcsco for finding a good reference to reticle.

Comment: Thanks to @dannyvarod for making the case for "crosshair box" as a colloquial term.

Answer (score 8):

I think the best term *is* "reticle." Businesses that make the glass used in cameras call them reticles. See the images on this site: http://www.reticles.com/reticles_kr900.htm.

Comment: Non of the top search results for "reticle" (including definition and images) seem more relevant than the top search results for "crosshair".

Comment: "crosshair" refers to two perpendicular lines that intersect. If you look at the image provided, no such lines exist.  http://www.thefreedictionary.com/cross+hair  http://www.thefreedictionary.com/reticle

Comment: Strange that this got voted down (not by me) and the later answer (with the same term) didn't.

Comment: Perhaps because the other one included a reference to back up the assertion, while this one is simply a matter of personal opinion (downvote not mine).

Comment: Good job finding that reference. That alone gives me the confidence to use the word "reticle." Although, I might still say "focus frame" to be more colloquial, since most people will not know what a reticle is.

Answer (score 1):

Well going to the actual source of QR codes - the company who invented them ([Denso Corporation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denso)) don't seem to have given that a particular name at all.

The products that they sell refer to that roughly in equal measure as the '[Reading Area](http://www.denso-adc.com/products/gt15)' or the '[Scanning Area](http://www.denso-wave.com/en/adcd/product/qrcode/handy_terminal/bht-800q.html)'.

Even the actual patent for QR codes: ([Optically readable two-dimensional code and method and apparatus using the same](http://worldwide.espacenet.com/publicationDetails/originalDocument?CC=US&NR=5726435A&KC=A&FT=D&ND=7&date=19980310&DB=EPODOC&locale=en_EP)) doesn't detail the actual guide lines, only going as far as to state that it is an 'image pickup device'.

You could *possibly* refer to it as a 'CCD Area', as a CCD (Charge-Coupled Device) is the type of image sensor that QR codes use (see this patent: [Optical information reading apparatus](http://www.freepatentsonline.com/y2006/0054844.html) - also from Denso) but that's not really the most intuitive term.

So basically, it seems like the specific term is still up-for-grabs. Reticule, 'Reading Area' or 'Guidelines' or whatever makes the most sense to the user really.

Comment: CCD is a type of image sensor used in many digital cameras, however, it has nothing to do with the marked area - the entire picture (including the area outside the boundaries of the marked area) is received from an image processing result above the energy measured by the CCD.

Comment: @DannyVarod yes, it's possible I misinterpreted the term there. The 'CCD area sensor' I took to mean as the CCD sensor scans the area in which the data is held, hence 'CCD Area' but that may be bad interpretation on my part.

Comment: So reading or scanning or viewfinder or crosshair - **area** or **box** are the common terms. Only 8 combinations. :-)

Comment: Haha, yeah it doesn't seem like there *is* a proper term for it. If even the *developers* of QR codes have (at least) two terms for the 'reticule in the scanning reading area box' then i think it's just whatever makes cognitive sense that can be used. Whatever takes the least amount of explaining to the people you're presenting it to.

Comment: I doubt "reticle" will ever catch on - it just doesn't sound right. Some people can't even remember how to spell it :-) (Referring to your last comment.)

Comment: @DannyVarod Ah yes, fair point. I have used that spelling in my answer too. Firefox built-in spellchecker verifies 'Reticule' but not 'Reticle' (but that's probably because Reticule actually means "a woman's small bag or purse" according to Google!)

Answer (score 0):

According to [ehow](http://www.ehow.com/how_8488499_read-qr-codes-iphone.html) it is called a reticle. But I usually just hear it called the QR reader.

Answer (score 0):

Cross hairs are meant for aiming (centering) and are not usually interactive.

The rectangular visualization's primary purpose is not centering of focus, but selecting the relevant part of the image for scanning. Theoretically user can change both size and location in the screen, therefore this is not a common cross hair.

The rectangular visualization enables the user to see and modify the "region of interest". (See definition of "region of interest" or ROI here [[Wikipedia]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Region_of_interest), [[Mathworks]](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/f19-13234.html), [[Wolfram]](http://library.wolfram.com/examples/roi/)).

I found that this rectange is refered to as ["**viewfinder box**"](http://acer-tr.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/16483/~/how-to-install-a-printer-with-acer-print), ["**viewfinder rectange**"](http://areacellphone.com/2010/05/howto-download-install-android-apps-using-qr-codes/), ["**viewfinder area**"](http://www.quickmark.cn/en/Info/android.asp), ["**crosshair box**"](http://www.cadtutor.net/forum/archive/index.php/t-17689.html) (or ["annoying yellow box around crosshair"](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1718837) in non-QR usage), however a more correct term (which is commonly used in image processing) would be "**region of interest**".

Relevent queries:

[viewfinder box](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22viewfinder+box%22+qr&hl=en&tbm=isch)
[viewfinder rectangle](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22viewfinder+rectangle%22+qr&hl=en&tbm=isch)
[viewfinder area](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22viewfinder+area%22+qr&hl=en&tbm=isch)

Answer (score 0):

I've written a number of QR code-reading apps, and have always called it a "reticle" in my code, because (son of a photographer here) I was always taught that *any* lines, grid, crosshair, or indicia overlaid on a view (like a viewfinder in a camera) were *all* called reticles. Hence, it's a general term: a crosshair overlaid on a view is *also* a kind of reticle. I can see why it's not such a good user-facing term however, as it's not a simple, common English descriptive term. So for user-facing purposes, I'd go with Apple's usage and call it the "Focus Area," even if it's not literally used for focusing the lens— the point is it's directing the user where to put the focus of their attention.